# Optimize postgresql query on dynamic databases

Tags: database, postgresql, doctrine

I have some optimization problem for my query using postgresql with databases that have differents data.

Let me explain :
Each customer have his own database with his own products.
But each customer can create their own fields and use the languages they want and the distribution channel they want.
So customer_1 one can have the following fields:

- price
- name
- ean_code
  With EN and DE languages and sending products to website_1 and website_2

Another customer_2 can have one the following fields :

- color
- name
- size
  With FR, IT and EN languages and sending products to website_2

Actually my data looks like that :
Product :

- id: uuid
- some infos nothing important related to my problem

ProductValues:

- id: uuid
- product_id: related to product table
- channel_id: related to a channel
- value: jsonb

The point is that the jsonb in value can change for every customer.
For customer_1 will have something like that :
value = `{"en": {"price": null, "name": "name_en, "ean_code": null}, "de": {"price": 5, "name": null, "ean_code": 123}}`

And customer_2:
value = `{"fr": {"color": "red", "name": "name_fr", "size": 2}, "it": {"color": "red", "name": "name_it", "size": 2}, "en": {"color": "red", "name": "name_en", "size": null}}`

The problem of that is that my query starts to get really slow when i get more than 1 million row with around 100/200 fields.
A simplified query for customer_2 could look like this :
`SELECT * FROM productattribute pa WHERE pa.value->'fr'->>'color' IS NOT NULL`

As nothing is indexed i'm not sure how to do that correctly without multiplicating my database size too much. Maybe my data structure is wrong as well, but if you have some ideas to improve that, I would be gratefull.

I tried indexing like this :
`CREATE INDEX test_index ON productvalues USING BTREE (((value->'fr'->>'color')::text));`

But it seems hard to maintain for every field.

Here is the EXPLAIN without any indexs on a smaller database

```
Seq Scan on productattribute pa  (cost=0.00..500.81 rows=47 width=278) (actual time=0.052..47.997 rows=9321 l
oops=1)
   Output: id, product_id, channel_id, value
   Filter: (((value -> 'fr'::text) ->> 'color'::text) IS NULL)
   Buffers: shared hit=25585
 Settings: search_path = 'public, "$user"'
 Planning Time: 0.102 ms
 Execution Time: 66.789 ms
```

I also tried created a GIN index like this
`CREATE INDEX test_index ON productattribute USING GIN (value);`
or
`CREATE INDEX test_index ON productattribute USING GIN (value->'en');`

But it doesn't change much

Comment: First you need the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement. Without this, you're blind. And when asking for help, we need that result as well, in plain text. Second, you most likely need a GIN index: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING